# ESX convert vmdk from sparse to thin without creating a new instance

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vmdk

I am using vmkfstools to create a thin provisioned vmdk from a sparse vmdk.  I would like to be able to just rename the vmdk and flat vmdk files to have the name of the original disk and then power on the VM and be on my way, but it seems that doesn't work.  I ended up moving the converted vmdks into a new folder and spinning up a new VM.  What is the proper procedure to continue using the original VM with the newly converted disks (or is it not possible)?

Comment: To be clear, are you simply trying to get the disks to match the name of the VM?  Also, do you have vCenter?

Answer (score 0):

The most "clean" way of doing this is

1. power off the VM
2. remove the old disk from the VM (VM settings dialog)
3. convert the vmdk
4. add newly created vmdk to VM (use existing virtual disk) (be sure to use same SCSI adapter/LUN)
5. power on VM and check if it works
6. delete old vmdk

Is this ESX or ESXi?